# How to access every single image-pixel, matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i want to change randomly every pixel of an image to 0

my code so far

```
randx = randsrc(512,512,[1 0]);

for n=1:1:512
    if (randx(n)==0)
        A(n)=0;
    end  
end
```

till now just the first column gets changed.
don't know how to change also the other ones.

thanks for help

Comment: Have a look at numpy index and slicing. It is quite important that you understand before proceeding. Then also you'll be able to solve the problem yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access your image with two index: row and column. Using only A(n) with n between 1 and 512 you're accessing only to the elements of the first column (note that your image has 512x512 = 262144 elements and you're only accessing to the first 512, i.e. to the first column).

Try using

```
for n=1:1:262144
```

instead. This will work!

Answer (score 1):

you can use any random function to generate an array the same size of your image. here for example I used `randsample`:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
p = [0.2 0.8]; % probabilities for 0 and 1
% randomly set pixels to 0
r = reshape(randsample([0 1],numel(I),true,p),size(I));
I(r == 0) = 0;
imshow(I);
```

[image]